# How to display recently created record link in visualforce Email Template without using an Apex Custom Controller?

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, email-template, custom-controller, standardcontroller

I have objects with lookup relationship "A"(Parent) and "B"(Child). Email need to be sent to User whenever a New record "B" is added on "A" and Email body should include URLs of A & B. Currently I am able to display both URL's but not able to find a way to get the most recent record of "B".

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following:

- Create a text field in `A` (parent) called `Most_Recent_B_Id__c` (length = 18)
- Install the [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary package](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) (free, GitHub - essential tool)
- Create a formula field in `B` (child) called `ID18__c` with value = `CASESAFEID()`
- Configure DLRS to rollup `ID18__c` into `Most_Recent_B_Id__c` based on the most recent `CreatedDate` of `B`. Details on this in [release notes](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries/issues/76)

Then, the parent will always have the ID of the most recent child and you can construct a link to that child either in the email template itself or via a HYPERLINK formula in `A`

*All that said, VF templates and custom component controllers offer a lot more flexibility and don't pollute your schema with artifacts just to make an email template easier to build.*